# python requests login using cookies

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to login to
https://sftp.mcxindia.com and then get file in the url

https://sftp.mcxindia.com/?Command=Download&File=%2FCommon%2FContract%20Master%2FCTCLContractMaster%2FMCXScrips.bcp

I am currently unable to login (user id and password are correct I know)
I tried

```
In [2]: import requests
   ...: import urllib
   ...: import urllib2

In [3]: session = requests.Session()

In [15]: payload = {'user':'####','pword':'####'}

In [16]: r = session.post('https://sftp.mcxindia.com', data=payload,verify=False)

In [17]: r
Out[17]: <Response [401]>
```

I think its login method is something through cookies whic I am not confident about. I looked at the login button event and found cookie value is set.

Can anyone help why I am unable to login

Added form html https://pastebin.com/jLZHBbgr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the url to which you are posting is wrong

```
r = session.post('https://sftp.mcxindia.com/Web%20Client/Login.xml?Command=Login&Sync=1505978085429', data=payload,verify=False)
```

Comment: how did you find the url `https://sftp.mcxindia.com/Web%20Client/Login.xml?`Command=Login&Sync=1505978085429` and I think this url may change everyday (assuming the large number written at the end)

Comment: saw the url being called on the click of login button in the network tab in the developer option of chrome

Comment: you can do a GET request on that link and open a file in binary format and save the response into that file

Comment: yes that works for me. Coming back to the url you figured out correctly. I think that url can change, so we should ideally find that url from the script directly right ? btw thanks a ton pandit !

Comment: Yes the url can change and yes it would be advisable to read the script. I wish i was a pandit  :D

Comment: can you suggest a way to find xml url (which you found) from normal url `https://sftp.mcxindia.com`. Basically scrape xml url first and then post

Comment: not sure about this but one way is using beautiful soup(a python library) to analyse the form and see to which link is it posting or the functions being called to create the address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154959/discussion-between-pythonrcpp-and-vivek-jha).

Comment: Not Able To Find Link to download McxScrips.bcp File Without Login . Help.